# How InputStream's read() method is implemented?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

For the specific task I am trying to override `read()` method for my custom class that extends InputStream.

So far my implementation is:

```
private ArrayList<byte[]> inputBuffer = new ArrayList<>(); 
...
@Override
public int read(@NonNull byte[] b) throws IOException {
    if (inputBuffer.size() > 0) {
        b = inputBuffer.get(0);
        inputBuffer.remove(0);
    } else
        return -1;

    return b.length;
}
```

And I am adding data to my `InputStream` like this:

```
boolean writeDataToInputStream(byte[] data) {
    int arrSize = inputBuffer.size();
    if (data.length > 0) {
        inputBuffer.add(data);
    }
    return arrSize < inputBuffer.size();
}
```

I've read documentation, I know how this method works by default. But I need somehow to pass `ArrayList` element to input parameter `byte[] b`.

I've been coding in java for few years and yet I've never put attention to how this method is actually implemented. How can I pass data to an incoming parameter and return the number of bytes from my ArrayList's element written?

I have to use custom Socket specifically for BLE w/ Input and Output stream due to my architecture, where I use WiFi socket, BT socket.

Please uncover this mystery for me.

Comment: private ArrayList<byte[]> inputBuffer = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: yes, but how do I put bytes properly to the input byte array that I will use in totally different class?

Comment: java 7 (bc it's Android). Does Java go native with read() method and passes the data to INPUT parameter using pointers?

Comment: where is the inputBuffer being populated? Is it filled via some native method implementation in a separate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your own `InputStream`, the only method that you have to implement since it is an `abstract` method is [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) which is also much less error prone than implementing `read(byte[] b)` and/or `read(byte b[], int off, int len)`. Moreover please note that the default implementation of `read(byte b[], int off, int len)` already checks the arguments for you so unless you want to revalidate the arguments yourself, you should implement `read()` only.

So in your case this method could be:

```
// Current index in the last byte array read
private int index;
private List<byte[]> inputBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
...
@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
   if (inputBuffer.isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    // Get first element of the List
    byte[] bytes = inputBuffer.get(0);
    // Get the byte corresponding to the index and post increment the current index
    byte result = bytes[index++];
    if (index >= bytes.length) {
        // It was the last index of the byte array so we remove it from the list
        // and reset the current index
        inputBuffer.remove(0);
        index = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

However if you really want to implement `read(byte b[], int off, int len)`, here is how it could look like:

```
@Override
public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    // Check parameters
    if (b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else if (len == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (inputBuffer.isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }
    int read = 0;
    // Iterate as long as don't get the expected bytes amount and the list is not empty
    do {
        byte[] bytes = inputBuffer.get(0);
        int lg = Math.min(bytes.length - index, len);
        // Copy the bytes from "bytes" to "b"
        System.arraycopy(bytes, index, b, off, lg);
        // Update all counters
        read += lg;
        off += lg;
        index += lg;
        len -= lg;
        if (index >= bytes.length) {
            // It was the last index of the byte array so we remove it from the list
            // and reset the current index
            inputBuffer.remove(0);
            index = 0;
        }
    } while (read < len && !inputBuffer.isEmpty());

    return read;
}
```

Comment: Just tested 2nd method and it works like magic! So the main trick is in using System.arraycopy with dest being input parameter? And somehow it just copies data to already created array object. Is it because byte b[] is passed here by reference?

Comment: that's where I was laking the reference magic :D native ftw, I guess :D Just curious, is there any way to achieve same effect w/o native calls?