# Creating Thumbnail from video on S3 without downloading

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, video-capture

There are some video files (mostly .mp4) stored in S3. They could be rather big. I need to get a thumbnail images for the video files - let's say 0.5 second's frame (to skip possible black screen etc.).

I can create the thumbnail if I download whole file but it's too long and I am trying to avoid this and download some minimal fragment.

I know [how to download first N bytes from AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537884/how-to-get-first-n-bytes-of-file-from-s3-url) - request with specified range but the problem is the video file piece is corrupted and is not recognized as correct video.

I tried to emulate header bytes retrieving with the code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D://temp//1.mp4");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D://temp//1_cut.mp4");
        ) {
            byte[] buf=new byte[1000000];
            fis.read(buf);
            fos.write(buf);
            fos.flush();
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }

}
```

To work with static file but the result `1_cut.mp4` is not valid. Neither player can recognize it nor `avconv` library.

Is there any way to download just fragment of video file and create an image from the fragment?

Comment: If the file wasn't prepared with progressive streaming in mind you will not be able to download part of it and begin the decode process. You can test this out with a larger publicly accessible file in VLC or even chrome browser; when you open and play the http link, does it buffer the entire file or does it start playing before its fully downloaded?

Comment: @Mike It's not a problem to download part. Let's exclude the aws part at all. Suppose we have a video file and cut a part of file. Is it possible to create a thumbnail (or screenshot) from the piece of file?

Comment: Can you descibe much more detail about the decoder you are implementing please?

Comment: I'm not at all confident that this will work, but it may be worth investigating repairing the downloaded fragment. This site (https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/repair-corrupt-video-file-vlc-media-player/) claims that VLC can repair partial video files in some cases.

Comment: @Harry I am not implementing any decoder. I need thumbnails (snapshots) from video file. Let's say 10th frame of video which is really big. I don't want to download the file to get 10th frame.

Comment: @jarmod I thought about the approach. It would work but I need to do this from backend. It would be great if you can recommend a java lib (or at least command line lib to call from java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if you need full java implementation but in case your file is accessible with direct or signed URL at S3 and you are ok to use `ffmpeg` than following should do the trick.

```
ffmpeg -i $amazon_s3_signed_url -ss 00:00:00.500 -vframes 1 thumbnail.png
```

You can use [Amazon Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html) to create a pre-signed URL and then execute the command above to create a thumbnail.

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
                new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); 
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest); 
String urlString = url.toString();

Runtime run  = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = run.exec("ffmpeg -i " + urlString +" -ss 00:00:00.500 -vframes 1 thumbnail.png");
```

Comment: Tried this with public URLs (I use avconv lib but options are the same). Works fine when I use `http://some.path.here` but fails when I try HTTPS the same url `https://some.path.here` fails

Comment: Seems it just a fork of the `ffmpeg`, so you can try `-protocols` argument which should list the protocols supported, if https is not in the list, you need to recompile the `avconv` with `openssl` enabled.
For example this lists the supported protocols for ffmpeg `ffmpeg -protocols`

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach just to download a random number of sequencial bytes would require you to do repair the partial file that you downloaded... a huge amount of work.

One alternative solution to your question above might be like that:

[image]

You would need to forward all Disk I/O read requests from your decoder to the S3 bucket. In case your decoder (avconv) supports reading from an inputstream, here is a good example how to override the read method:

[How InputStream's read() method is implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916355/how-inputstreams-read-method-is-implemented)

Another alternative is to use existing drivers that just let you access the S3 bucket as it was a local drive:

Windows: https://tntdrive.com/

Linux: https://tecadmin.net/mount-s3-bucket-centosrhel-ubuntu-using-s3fs/#

Comment: The second approach would be an option. Use S3 as disk I mean. As for the first. Actually I don't have any decoder. I call avconv library similar as described in the answer of @Babl